# Delphi MREW implementation that favors readers?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, synchronization

Is there a Delphi implementation of an MREW (multiple read, exclusive write) lock, that favors reading over writing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the [TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/28258) already favors readers.

> As the name of the component implies,
>   a TMREWS should be used when there is
>   much reading and little writing to be
>   done. In addition, the READ operations
>   should be kept to a MINIMUM otherwise
>   your write threads could be left
>   waiting indefinitely.

It is in the SysUtils unit.

Answer (score 1):

Check out TJclMultiReadExclusiveWrite from the Project JEDI JCL (http://www.delphi-jedi.org/).  The constructor of that class supports a parameter that tell the code which to favor - readers, writers, or consider them to be equal.

Answer (score 0):

The standard Delphi realization (since Delphi 11) is: [`System.SyncObjs.TLightweightMREW`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SyncObjs.TLightweightMREW).