# Delphi2006 - Is there TList with TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-2006, synchronization, tlist

I have external application that is multithreaded and this app is using my custom dll to do some things from that threads.
In this dll I have 2 functions that read from and write some data to `TList`.
I need that list to be freely read by those threads but only one can write at a time, the rest must wait for their time to write.

My question:
 - is there in BDS 2006 a `TList` component that have TMREWSync capability or
 - maybe You know any free third-party component that I can use in my app or
 - maybe You have some customized `TList` code that can do things like this mentioned above.

**Edit**:
I need something like `TThreadList.LockList` but only for writing to that list.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delphi MREW implementation that favors readers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742915/delphi-mrew-implementation-that-favors-readers)

Comment: You don't understand, I need TList that have MREW capability, it's not the same question. There is TThreadList but it locks out all, reading is not possible until the lock is removed.

Comment: `TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer` is a synchro object. It doesn't have a container associated with it. You have to do that bit yourself.  It's very very easy to do that. Have you tried?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: No, I have not tried. it's easy for you but not for me. Can you show me some code, please?

Comment: @NevTon, put a wrapper class around a `TList` and protect access to the internal `TList` with a `TMREW` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple enough to put together a `TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer` and `TList` in the same manner as `TThreadList`. If you already know how these classes work, then you'll be able to follow the code below.

```
type
  TReadOnlyList = class
  private
    FList: TList;
    function GetCount: Integer;
    function GetItem(Index: Integer): Pointer;
  public
    constructor Create(List: TList);
    property Count: Integer read GetCount;
    property Items[Index: Integer]: Pointer read GetItem;
  end;

  TMREWList = class
  private
    FList: TList;
    FReadOnlyList: TReadOnlyList;
    FLock: TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function LockListWrite: TList;
    procedure UnlockListWrite;
    function LockListRead: TReadOnlyList;
    procedure UnlockListRead;
  end;

{ TReadOnlyList }

constructor TReadOnlyList.Create(List: TList);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FList := List;
end;

function TReadOnlyList.GetCount: Integer;
begin
  Result := FList.Count;
end;

function TReadOnlyList.GetItem(Index: Integer): Pointer;
begin
  Result := FList[Index];
end;

{ TMREWList }

constructor TMREWList.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FList := TList.Create;
  FReadOnlyList := TReadOnlyList.Create(FList);
  FLock := TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer.Create;
end;

destructor TMREWList.Destroy;
begin
  FLock.Free;
  FReadOnlyList.Free;
  FList.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TMREWList.LockListWrite: TList;
begin
  FLock.BeginWrite;
  Result := FList;
end;

procedure TMREWList.UnlockListWrite;
begin
  FLock.EndWrite;
end;

function TMREWList.LockListRead: TReadOnlyList;
begin
  FLock.BeginRead;
  Result := FReadOnlyList;
end;

procedure TMREWList.UnlockListRead;
begin
  FLock.EndRead;
end;
```

This is the most basic implementation possible. If you wish you could add some more bells and whistles in the manner of `TThreadList`.

Comment: Thanks, but I have one additional question: using Your solution, can I lock for write while being already locked for read?

Comment: You can if `TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer` allows that.

Comment: Hipothesis situation is: `with List.LockListRead do try` ... do something ... `List.LockListWrite.Items[x]:=Nil; List.UnlockListWrite;` ... do something ... `finally List.UnlockListRead; end;`. Can I do that?

Comment: You need to understand `TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer` to answer that. You simply asked if there was a way to have a list that was synchronized using `TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer`. And that's what I answered. Are you really going to start pumping me for details on `TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer` now? In the comments to my answer?

Comment: No, a read lock cannot safely be upgraded to a write lock. During the process to get the write lock, the read lock must be released, and there might be a chance for another process to get the write access instead.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Ok, sorry for that. I'm trying this super cool and short solution of Yours. I hope this works as I need it, will inform about the results later.